# MySQL syntax error using NPM 'mysql' module

Tags: mysql

I'm using Node.js and the [mysql NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to interact with a MySQL 5.7.14 instance.  I'm getting an error about a syntax error in a query I'm making:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO votes (user_uid, node_uid, sentiment) VALUES ('fakeid-123'' at line 1

At first I thought this must be a mistake I made in MySQL-escaping my input values, which I'm doing with the following in Node.js:

```
query =
  'START TRANSACTION; ' +
  'INSERT INTO votes (user_uid, node_uid, sentiment) VALUES (' +
    connection.escape(user_uid) + ', ' +
    connection.escape(node_uid) + ', ' +
    connection.escape(newValue) +
  '); ' +
  'UPDATE nodes SET votification=votification+' + newValue + ' ' +
  'WHERE uid=' + connection.escape(node_uid) + ';' +
  'COMMIT;'
connection.query(query, function(err, rows) { //.. blah blah
```

However, I added a console log to check the value of the `query` variable immediately before it is passed to `connection.query`, and I'm getting a perfectly legal-looking set of queries:

> START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO votes (user_uid, node_uid, sentiment) VALUES ('fakeid-123', 'start', 1); UPDATE nodes SET votification=votification+1 WHERE uid='start';COMMIT;

However, it's giving the above error.  I tried copy-pasting this query string verbatim into a MySQL console session, and it performed admirably.

Is this an error in the NPM/mysql module?  Does it not support transactions in this way, somehow?  What else could be wrong?  I assume the queries and transaction formation are okay, since they work when copy/pasted into MySQL directly.

For what it's worth, I'm using this module extensively and this is coincidentally the only query where I get such a failure, and the only place I'm using a transaction.  I'm using a transaction here because I don't want to make these two calls "separately."  I know the `connection` object is solid because I'm using it elsewhere in this scope with no problems.

Note/edit: I do see the [documentation for the mysql NPM module on transactions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions) (and I'm implementing this now instead), this is a much clunkier way to implement what I want and I'd like to understand why passing what I'm passing is failing.

Comment: Have you tried to break this into three queries?

Comment: I was hoping to maintain the atomicity offered by transactions.  I'm specifically trying to avoid making three separate queries to prevent any "race conditions" or interference from other users potentially accessing the same rows in the DB.

Comment: Understood. I noodles around for a minute and provided an answer (which worked overt here) below.

Comment: It's a real mess to write against the low-level `mysql` driver and I'd strongly encourage you to use something with a tiny bit more abstraction. [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) is a good multi-database layer that gives you a lot of functionality without over-complicating things and in particular supports **prepared statements** which make escaping mistakes less likely to occur. Manually escaping things is always risky and error-prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Playing around I came up with this while checking gave documentation:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true})
```

Multiple queries are disabled by default.

Comment: I'm using a connection pool, rather than just a connection, but I will give this a try based on your answer: `var pool = mysql.createPool({multipleStatements: true, /*others*/});` I'm not worried about the security reasons they mention for avoiding this technique since I'm escaping every value ever sourced from outside the scope from which I'm making queries.  (PS: it worked, thank you!!)